# Как скрыть товары (по типу товара) из архивов WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Сайт на WordPress с плагином WooCommerce. Хочу сделать доступ к определенному типу товаров только по ссылке. На ум пришло лишь скрыть их на всех страницах архивах. Нашла в гугле функцию, которая скрывает по таксономии, но не могу переделать так, что бы скрывало по типу продукта - вариативный.

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {
 
    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
 
    $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => array( 'clothing' ), // Don't display products in the clothing category on the shop page.
           'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );
 
 
    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариативный продукт имеет пост тип `product_variation`.

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() ) {

        $post_types = $q->get( 'post_type' );
        $post_types = is_array( $post_types ) ? $post_types : [ $post_types ];
        $post_types = array_diff( $post_types, [ 'product_variation' ] );
        $q->set( $post_types );

    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

В условие `if ( ! $q->is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() ) {` добавьте еще что-то чтобы исключать и не исключать вариативные товары)